# Add titles list in job search

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

## What

- I want to choose from a fixed list of specific job titles (such a list would be generated as a result of a search, like "Developer").

## How

- This is what it looks like on LinkedIn:

[image: linkedin title filter screenshot]

## Why

This would allow to filter out **many** irrelevant results, for wrapping keywords in quotes (Ex.: "keyword") doesn't filter out postings where those keywords are mentioned in the posting *page*, even if they are not in the *title*.